# Referencing IIS Application

Tags: html, iis

I have a default web site setup with 2 applications.

I would like each application to be considered root.

So in my scripts if I were to have a reference like this :

```
document.write('<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\style\style.css" />');
```

the \ is referencing from root.

Problem is my application has a path like this http://mysite/myapp.

So to get the above example working I would need :

```
document.write('<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\myapp\style\style.css" />');
```

How can I use applications or virtual directories and not create a 2nd web site and still ensure each application is treated as root application?